# What is the fomula of polynomial time of solving positive definite symmetric linear system

Tags: linear-solver, efficiency

For a positive definite symmetric linear system, Cholesky decomposition based method should be the best solver which has a rough `n^3/3` flops requirement.

What is the fomula of flops including `n^2`, `n` items? Is there any such reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From *Numerical Linear Algebra* by Trefethen and Bau, page 175, it seems that the formula is

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j = k + 1}^{n} (2(n - j + 1) + 1).
\end{align}

Eyeballing it, it seems to agree with the formula given by Boyd in his [convex optimization notes](http://www.ee.ucla.edu/ee236b/lectures/num-lin-alg.pdf): $(1/3)n^{3} + 2n^{2}$.

Comment: thank you very much! Is there other formula for `LU` decomposition and `Householder` methods in solving linear systems?

Comment: Additionally, in `Cholesky` decomposition, there are at least `n` times `square root` used; how to count such operations?

Comment: A square root will cost as much as a fixed multiple of floating point additions or multiplications, so it's still $O(n)$ of course. For even moderately large matrices, the $O(n^2)$ and $O(n^3)$ terms dominate, so whatever is linear in $n$ is not important and the exact factor in front of the linear term doesn't matter.

Comment: thank you very much! Does the conclusion hold even for multiple precision computation via `GMP` multiple precision library?

Comment: @LCFactorization: It is likely to hold; the conjecture could be tested to leading order by plotting the logarithm of execution time of a Cholesky factorization versus the logarithm of the size of the square, positive definite matrix. I suspect that precision effects also play a role, as the preferred multiplication algorithms used by GMP will likely change depending upon the number of digits used in your multiple precision computation.